# Word Unscrambling Program - C++

Tags: c++, arrays, string, pointers

Hi I'm working a program to unscramble a set of letters and output all the words that can be made from that set of letters, for example: If i inputed the letters "vlei", the program would output "live", "evil", and "vile".

So far I have looked through the internet about this quiiiite a bit and can't find anything on my specific questions relevant to my skill level at this point (level 2 noob).

So far I have gotten as far as making all the possible combinations from the the given letters. Excluding any that are less than 7 letters, which is a problem.

This is the code I have so far:

```
string letter;
char newWord[7];

    int main()
{

cout << "Type letters here: ";
cin >> letter;


for(int i = 0 ; i < 7 ; i++)
{   
    for(int j = 0 ; j < 7 ; j++)
    {
        for(int k = 0 ; k < 7 ; k++)
        {
            for(int l = 0 ; l < 7 ; l++)
            {
                for(int m = 0 ; m < 7 ; m++)
                {
                    for(int n = 0 ; n < 7 ; n++)
                    {
                        for(int o = 0 ; o < 7 ; o++)
                        {

                            sprintf(newWord, "%c%c%c%c%c%c%c", letter[i], letter[j], letter[k], letter[l], letter[m], letter[n], letter[o]);

                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
}

return 0;

}
```

I was wondering if anyone has any experience with anything like this, and can offer and hints or advice.

Specifically what I'm having difficulty with is how to read in a .txt file to use as a dictionary to compare words to.
Also, I was having trouble using `strcmp()` which is what I was planning to use to compare the scrambled words to the dictionary. So if there are any other maybe simpler ways to compare the two strings, that would be greatly appreciated.

Thanks in advance.

---

Hi guys, so I've just finished my program and I hope it can help someone else. Thanks a lot for all your help.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
#include <string>
#include <cstring>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <algorithm>
#include <vector>
#include <array>

using namespace std;



//declaring variables
int i;
int scores[531811]; //array for scores of found words
string wordlist[531811]; //array for found matched words
string word[531811]; //array of strings for dictionary words about to be read it
string tester;//string for scrambled letters that will be read in

int scorefinder(string scrab) //SCORE FINDER FUNCTION
{
    int score = 0;
    int x = 0;
    int j = 0;
    while (scrab[j])
    {
        char ltr = toupper(scrab[j]); //converts to all caps

        //assings values to each letter and adds it to itself
        if(ltr == 'A' || ltr == 'E' || ltr == 'I' || ltr == 'L' || ltr == 'N' || ltr == 'O' || ltr == 'R' || ltr == 'S' || ltr == 'T' || ltr == 'U')
            x += 1;
        else if(ltr == 'D' || ltr == 'G')
            x += 2;
        else if(ltr == 'B' || ltr == 'C' || ltr == 'M' || ltr == 'P')
            x += 3;
        else if(ltr == 'F' || ltr == 'H' || ltr == 'V' || ltr == 'W' || ltr == 'Y')
            x += 4;
        else if(ltr == 'K')
            x += 5;
        else if(ltr == 'J' || ltr == 'X')
            x += 8;
        else if(ltr == 'Q' || ltr == 'Z')
            x += 10;
        ++j;
    }
    score = x;
    return score;
}

int main () {

//READS IN DICTIONARY
    ifstream file("words.txt"); //reads in dictionary
    if (!file.is_open()){ //checks if file is being NOT read correctly
        cout << "BROEKN \n"; //prints error message if so
    }
    if(file.is_open()){ //checks if file IS being read correctly
        for(int i = 0; i < 531811; i++){ 
            file >> word[i]; //read in each word from the file and 
        }   //assigns each to it's position in the words array
    }
//END OF READ IN DICTIONARY

    cout << "Enter scrambled letters: ";
    cin >> tester; //reads in scrambled letters

    sort(tester.begin(),tester.end()); //sorts scrambled letters for next_permutation
    while (next_permutation(tester.begin(),tester.end())){  //while there are still permutations available
        for(i=0;i<531811;i++){
            if ( is_permutation (word[i].begin(),word[i].end(), tester.begin())){
                wordlist[i] = word[i]; //assigns found word to foundword array
                scores[i] = scorefinder(word[i]); //assigns found word score to foundscore array
            }
        }
    }

    //PRINTS OUT ONLY MATCHED WORDS AND SCORES
    for(i=0;i<531811;i++){
        if(scores[i]!=0){
            cout << "Found word: " << wordlist[i] << " " << scores[i] << "\n";
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: what is the question ?

Comment: How would your program look if the word had 10 letters ? And dous your code work ?

Comment: @AndreiAlexandruAgape Sorry I accidentally posted too early, I just edited my post. Mostly it's just asking for advice on how to compare the scrambled words, and the dictionary words, and how to read in a dictionary into my program.

Comment: @MichaelWalz I believe if it had 10 letters I would simply add 3 more `for` loops after the ones I already have, but that is a problem I feel like I can work on after I already have the basics working. And yeah it works somewhat, I've gotten it to print all the possible words given 7 letters. Minus any words that are less than 7 letters, which I don't know why.

Comment: you need a list with the english words, a function that permutes your letters and a function that checks if the permuted letters creates a word that can be found in your list. read letters, do permutation - check if it is a word from your list. if it is, print it on the screen, if not, skip. do next permutation until no more permutation are possible. this is also the solution provided by @Amol Bavannavar. your solution is not scalable and does not cover all possible situations.

Comment: @AndreiAlexandruAgape Yeah that's pretty much how I was trying to make it, I couldn't think of/find any other way to permute the letters, so that's why I settled with all those nested for loops.

I do have a list of english words in the main file where my .cpp file is. I need to figure out how to implement it, or read it into my code. And also the comparisons are hard to figure out for me as well. I was trying to use strcmp(), but it was having issues because I dont have that well a grasp on how it's supposed to work with pointers. Any suggestions?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Suppose you have found a word list in the form of plain text file on the Internet, you may load all the words into a vector for string first.

```
ifstream word_list_file("word_list.txt");
string buffer;
vector<string> all_words;
while (getline(word_list_file, buffer))
    all_words.push_back(buffer);
```

Then we want to compare the input letters with the each entry of `all_words`. I suggest using `std::is_permutation`. It compares two sequence regardless the order. But it can have trouble when the two sequence has different length, so compare the length yourself first.

```
// Remember to #include <algorithm>
bool match(const string& letters, const string& each_word)
{
    if (letters.size() != each_word.size())
        return false;

    return is_permutation(begin(letters), end(letters), begin(each_word));
}
```

Note that I have not tested my codes. But that's the idea.

---

An edit responsing the comment:

In short, just use `std::string`, not `std::array`. Or copy my `match` function directly, and invoke it. This will be easier for your case.

Details:

`std::is_permutation` can be used with any container and any element type. For example:

```
#include <string>
#include <array>
#include <vector>
#include <list>
#include <algorithm>
using namespace std;

int main()
{
//Example 1
    string str1 = "abcde";
    string str2 = "ecdba";
    is_permutation(begin(str1), end(str1), begin(str2));

//Example 2
    array<double, 4> array_double_1{ 4.1, 4.2, 4.3, 4.4 };
    array<double, 4> array_double_2{ 4.2, 4.1, 4.4, 4.3 };
    is_permutation(begin(array_double_1), end(array_double_1), begin(array_double_2));

//Example 3
    list<char> list_char = { 'x', 'y', 'z' };
    string str3 = "zxy";
    is_permutation(begin(list_char), end(list_char), begin(str3));

// Exampl 4
    short short_integers[4] = { 1, 2, 3, 4 };
    vector<int> vector_int = { 3, 4, 2, 1 };
    is_permutation(begin(list_char), end(list_char), begin(str3));

    return 0;
}
```

- Example 1 uses `std::string` as containers of `char`s, which is exactly how my `match` function work.
- Example 2 uses two `array`s of `double` of size 4.
- Example 3 even uses two different kinds of containers, with the same element types. (Have you heard of `std::list'? Never mind, just focus on our problem first.)
- Example 4 is even stranger. One container is old style raw array, another is a `std::vector`. There are also two element types, `short` and `int`, but they are both integer. (The exact difference between `short` and `int` is not relevant here.)

Yet, all four cases can use `is_permutation`. Very flexiable.

The flexibility is enabled by the following facts:

1. `is_permutation` is not exactly a function. It is a function template, which is a language feature to generate new functions according to the data type you pass to it.
2. The containers and `is_permutation` algorithm do not know each other. They communicate through a middleman called "iterator". The `begin` and `end` functions together give us a pair of iterators representing the "range" of elements.

It requires more studies to understand these facts. But the general idea is not hard. Also, these facts are also true for other algorithms in the Standard Library.

Comment: Wow `is_permutation` seems so perfect for my program then. I will definitely look into using that then. Also how to use vectors when reading in a text file. Vectors are totally new to me at the moment. I have to look into those as well. Thank you for your answer!

Comment: Hi I was wondering if you had any advice on how to go about using `is_permutation()`. 


I've been looking into it a lot but I can't figure out how to change what `is_permutation` is trying to compare. The closest I've come is changing `std::array<int,5> foo = {1,2,3,4,5};` into `std::array<char,5> foo = {"word};` and comparing it to `std::array<char,5> bar = {"drow"};` for a `true` return. But if the word is not in quotations it doesn't work, and therefore doesn't allow me to change the words being compared very easily. Any advice?

Comment: @DominikFigueroa Does your example of `std::array<int,5> foo = {1,2,3,4,5}` come from cplusplus.com ? I think I'd better append some more information to my answer, so please wait. Mean while, you can use my `match` function directly.

Answer (score 1):

Well, what you need is some sort of comparison. C++ doesn´t know, what a right word in english is. So you may need a wordlist. Then you can Brutforce(that´s what you´re doing at the moment) until you find a match.

For comparing your brutforced result, you may use a .txt with as many english words as you can find. Then you have to use a FileStream for iterating through every word and comparing it to your brutforce result.

After you sucessfully unscrambled a word, you should think about your solution again. As you can see, you are limited to a specific amount of chars which is not that nice.

This sounds like an interesting Task for a beginner ;)

Comment: Oh a filestream sounds like it would be perfect for what I'm trying to do. i.e get my list of words into my code. 

And yeah I do have to think of a better way to permute than all those nested for() loops. 

Any suggestions on where to look to find more information on FileStreamin? Is that like a 3rd party thing?

Answer (score 0):

Try this :

```
# include <stdio.h>

/* Function to swap values at two pointers */
void swap (char *x, char *y)
{
    char temp;
    temp = *x;
    *x = *y;
    *y = temp;
}

/* Function to print permutations of string
   This function takes three parameters:
   1. String
   2. Starting index of the string
   3. Ending index of the string. */
void permute(char *a, int i, int n) 
{
   int j; 
   if (i == n)
     printf("%s\n", a);
   else
   {
        for (j = i; j <= n; j++)
       {
          swap((a+i), (a+j));
          permute(a, i+1, n);
          swap((a+i), (a+j)); //backtrack
       }
   }
} 

/* Driver program to test above functions */
int main()
{
   char a[] = "vlei";  
   permute(a, 0, 3);
   getchar();
   return 0;
}
```

Comment: I found this solution on http://www.geeksforgeeks.org/write-a-c-program-to-print-all-permutations-of-a-given-string/

Comment: I think he wants to do this on his own for training purposes.

Comment: Yeah, but if he want's permutation's then he can use this code

Comment: Hmmm this looks like it could be useful. It seems much more efficient than all those nested loops I've got.

Comment: And anyhow he must have to find permutation's for dictionary checking too... what do you think??

Comment: @DominikFigueroa: If you want to generate permutations you should use the standard library [`std::next_permutation`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/next_permutation) instead of this nonsense.

Comment: @Blastfurnace So I've been looking into `is_permutation` and the like, a lot today. And I can't seem to figure out how to manipulate the `std::array<int,5> foo = {1,2,3,4,5};` or `std::array<int,5> bar = {3,1,4,5,2};` with out a million compiling errors.

I don't understand how to change what is inside the arrays that are being compared to each other, also how to make them strings of letters instead of numbers.

Comment: I'm not sure where you're stuck but [this live demo on ideone.com](http://ideone.com/aKcUXo) shows how to use `std::next_permutation` to produce all arrangements of a string. The same method applies to any container that provides at least bidirectional iterators.